# how to animate in imageView array android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating an arcade game and I want the obstacales (enemies) move smoothly to the buttom of the screen.
I put image View in the Imageview array and I want them to move smoothly between cells.

this is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_balloon);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    loadDrawables();
    designBoardGame();
    playGame();

}

private void playGame() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    startNote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startNote);
    Move = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Move);
    Move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View d) {
            if(gameOn){
            start = true;}
            startNote.setText("");
            playerMove();
        }
    });
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (start) {
                        createEnemies();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, delay, period * 2);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (start) {
                        advanceEnemies();
                        score.setText("score " + Score+" level "+lvl);
                    }
                        if (period > 300 && Score > lvlUp) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            levelUp();
                        }

                }
            });
        }
    }, delay, period);
}
```

this is the function that build the enemies:

```
public void createEnemies() {
    enemyList.add(new Enemy());
    map[enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateX()][enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateY()] = 2;
    ivCell[enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateX()][enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateY()].setImageDrawable(drawCell[2]);
    enemyList.add(new Enemy(enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1)));
    map[enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateX()][enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateY()] = 2;
    ivCell[enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateX()][enemyList.get(enemyList.size() - 1).getCoordinateY()].setImageDrawable(drawCell[2]);

}
```

and this is the one that move them down (now they going down in jumps):

```
public void advanceEnemies() {
    List<Enemy> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    TranslateAnimation enemyMove= new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,sizeOfCell);
    for (Enemy enemy : enemyList) {
        map[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()] = 0;
        ivCell[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()].setImageDrawable(drawCell[0]);
        enemy.move();
        map[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()] = 2;
        ivCell[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()].setImageDrawable(drawCell[2]);
        if (enemy.getCoordinateY() == player.getCoordinateY()) {
            if (enemy.getCoordinateX() == player.getCoordinateX() && gameOn) {
                gameOver();
            }
            toRemove.add(enemy);
            map[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()] = 0;
            ivCell[enemy.getCoordinateX()][enemy.getCoordinateY()].setImageDrawable(drawCell[0]);
            if(gameOn){
            Score++;
            }
        }
      }
    enemyList.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

this is the function that build the map and the imageView array:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void designBoardGame() {
    sizeOfCell = Math.round((ScreenWidth() - 64) / col);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams IpRow = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(sizeOfCell * row, sizeOfCell);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams IpCell = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(sizeOfCell, sizeOfCell);
    LinearLayout Sky = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Sky);
    //Create cells
    for (int ya = 0; ya < col; ya++) {
        // makes a row
        LinearLayout linRow = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        for (int xa = 0; xa < row; xa++) {
            // makes a cell
            ivCell[xa][ya] = new ImageView(getContext());
            if (xa == 1 && ya == col-1) {
                map[xa][ya] = 1;
                ivCell[xa][ya].setImageDrawable(drawCell[1]);
            }

            linRow.addView(ivCell[xa][ya], IpCell);

        }

        Sky.addView(linRow, IpRow);
    }

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @jhhoff02 I don't think he's using C#. This looks like java only

Comment: it is java only